# How to list multiple fields in "FIELDS" parameter in PyQGIS processing.run ()?

Tags: qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

The QGIS "remove duplicates by attribute" tool allows you to remove duplicates across multiple fields.

But how can I list multiple fields when I run this tool with pyqgis processing?

```
alg_params = {
    'INPUT': Layer,
    'FIELDS': ['field_1', 'field_2'], # does not work
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
}
fixLayer = processing.run("native:removeduplicatesbyattribute", alg_params)['OUTPUT']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for listing fields in pyqgis processing is:

```
'FIELDS': 'osm_id;osm_way_id',
```